# mRemoteNG settings from Putty

Tags: putty

I'm trying to get my settings from Putty loaded into mRemoteNG.  According to the thread below, once I select SSH version 2 as my protocol, I should have a list of settings to choose from in the Putty Session menu.  I definitely don't.  I have Default Settings only in mRemoteNG.  In Putty, I have a few that connect to machines, and most importantly, allow for middle-click paste.

http://forum.mremoteng.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1686

Thanks

Comment: I have some good experience with the mremoteng forums. Have you tried posting your question there?

Comment: Indeed I have not.  Usually have good luck here, but will try there.  For what it's worth, I think it's a Putty issue -- I tried SuperPutty and had the same issue. :-/  I also already have an account here.

Comment: The session selection shows up for me, maybe it's the version of putty you use. In the `Tools -> Options -> Advanced` menu of mRemoteNG, there is a button to launch putty to configure the sessions. Does that work?

Comment: That got the settings to load, but in turn has broken all connections (even w/ default settings).  Error is "connection failed cannot start process because a file name has not been provided".

Answer (score 2):

You need to have putty installed on your machine.
in mRemoteNG > Tools > Options > Advanced > Use custom putty path (Browse for putty.exe).

It worked for me !